# Is there an efficient way in LINQ to use a contains match if and only if there is no exact match?

Tags: c#, linq, search, closest

I have an application where I am taking a large number of 'product names' input by a user and retrieving some information about each product. The problem is, the user may input a partial name or even a wrong name, so I want to return the closest matches for further selection.

Essentially if product name A exactly matches a record, return that, otherwise return any contains matches. Otherwise return null.

I have done this with three separate statements, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. I am using LINQ to EF, but I materialize the products to a list first for performance reasons.

productNames is a List of product names (input by the user).
products is a List of product 'records'

```
var directMatches = (from s in productNames
                     join p in products on s.ToLower() equals p.name.ToLower() into result
                     from r in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new {Key = s, Product = r});

var containsMatches = (from d in directMatches
                      from p in products
                      where d.Product == null
                            && p.name.ToLower().Contains(d.Key)
                      select new { d.Key, Product = p });

var matches = from d in directMatches
              join c in containsMatches on d.Key equals c.Key into result
              from r in result.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new {d.Key, Product = d.Product ??  (r != null ? r.Product: null) };
```

Comment: At a minimum, if directMatches returns results, you can skip the second and third steps. But I agree with FreshCode. I can't think of any performance gains you could possibly see by retrieving all the data first, then doing your query in memory, rather than doing it against the database server.

Comment: this is a search problem. Where is the data coming from? Which database?

Comment: The problem is the number of inputs I am looking up at the same time. It is much slower for me to execute 300 sql queries than it is for me to just pull back the product records and filter them in memory. If I let EF write the sql the best it can do is a big 'in' statement which is fine for the exact match but the sql it tries to write for the 'contains' is terrible and will fail with too many products (due to the weird nesting). To top if off, I need to track which product input came back with which results, and which did not.

Comment: Please define "closest match". What do you want if the input is "hello" and you have "hi"/"hello1"/"1hello"/"helloA" in your list.

Comment: @Danny. I am not looking for soundex style matching, we have a number of products like 'Product 003A', and 'Product 003A Special', a simple contains works just fine because the users typically will put 'Product 003' or something similar. The code I listed works exactly the way I want, I just want to know if it can be written more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small to medium-sized list in-memory, take a look at [LiquidMetal](https://github.com/rmm5t/liquidmetal) and for phonetic matches, the [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) algorithm to rank the closest matches.

If you are using SQL Server, look into [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx), which is what Stack Overflow uses. Otherwise, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474229/keyword-to-sql-search/2523056#2523056) is how I [implemented](http://RhythmMusicStore.com) a keyword-based search.

Comment: Unfortunately the scenario I described above doesn't really lend itself to this solution. Even if it did, I would like to increase my understanding on LINQ's capabilities and see how my statements could be more efficient (in terms of LINQ).