# multiple keyword search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyword to SQL search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474229/keyword-to-sql-search)

I am using SQL SERVER 2008 & I am given to task to search for specific keywords( close to 100) relating to technical support notes. There are 20 columns and 1 million rows. The keywords I am looking is in 3 specific columns. How can I do it?

Column header : date, week, Qtr, Agent, Manager, Customer,Problem, Description, Solution,Order #,

I have to search for the keywords from Problem, Description, Solution columns. 
Problem : nvarchar
Description: nvarchar 
Solution : ntext

Keywords : bluetooth, cd, dvd, hard drive, motherboard, power supply, battery, ac adapter, windows, blue screen.

Sample data:
Problem :noise from fan Description : noise from fan Solution: noise from fan and system heating up. has A20 BIOS. checked support site and BIOS update available. customer to try that and get back to us with results

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have any sample data for the Problem, Description, and Solution columns?

Comment: Problem :noise from fan Description : noise from fan Solution: noise from fan and system heating up. has A20 BIOS. checked support site and BIOS update available. customer to try that and get back to us with results.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure for the best way. but one way can be this:

```
select * from table_name where 
Problem IN('bluetooth', 'cd', 'dvd', 'hard drive', 'motherboard', 'power supply', 'battery', 'ac adapter', 'windows', 'blue screen') 
OR 
Description IN('bluetooth', 'cd', 'dvd', 'hard drive', 'motherboard', 'power supply', 'battery', 'ac adapter', 'windows', 'blue screen') 
OR 
Solution IN('bluetooth', 'cd', 'dvd', 'hard drive', 'motherboard', 'power supply', 'battery', 'ac adapter', 'windows', 'blue screen');
```

Comment: sorry. this is for mysql database. tell me if you are using some other database and i will remove this answer.

Comment: But I have 100 or more such keywords  to be entered.

Comment: you can add those 100 keywords comma separated here. But I am not sure if this is the best and optimized solution.

Comment: Problem : nvarchar Description: nvarchar Solution : ntext